# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty 1/k$?

Tags: calculus

Random question but I was just wondering this and can't seem to find an answer anywhere. I want to say that it is infinity but I'm not quite sure.

Edit: Let me actually put it another way, since this is the question I'm really wondering: is it true that $\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{k=n}^\infty 1/k = \infty$ ?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that, for any $n\in\mathbb N$, $\sum_{k=n}^\infty1/k=\infty$?

Comment: Yes I understand that $\sum_{k=n}^\infty 1/k$ is obviously infinite for any natural number $n$ but I was unsure if this carried over to the limit

Comment: @Koby: as the value of the sum is undefined for every $n$, there is no "limit" nor "infimum", because there is *no sequence at all*.

Comment: Yeah but there is if you allow for extended real numbers, i.e. add in $\pm \infty$ which are just defined to be greater than or less than all real numbers, respectively, then in the extended real sense this seems like a sequence

Answer (score 3):

The expression you are considering doesn't make sense since the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) diverges.

For finite sum we have that

$$\sum_{k=n}^N \frac1k =\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac1k=H_N-H_{n-1}\sim\log N-\log (n-1)$$

Comment: Okay let me put it another way: what is $\inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{k=n}^\infty 1/k$?

Comment: @Koby This definition becomes meaningless in this way since for any $n$ $\sum_{k=n}^\infty 1/k=\infty$.

Comment: @Koby Anyway in some sense, with some abuse of notation, we could also assume that $\sup=\inf = \infty$ but it is not a proper definition of infimum.

Comment: Right, I understand that for any $n$ this is the case but does this not just then imply that $\inf{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of the sum is simply infinity? I don't think that we can just avoid the question by claiming that $\inf{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{k = n}^\infty 1/k$ is meaningless

Comment: Why do you think that this is abuse of notation? Thanks so much by the way for the help, just trying to understand this further

Comment: @Koby Because we should assume $a_n=\infty$ for any $n$ but as we know $\infty$ is not a number. Anyway we can extend the definition and conclude that $\inf = \infty$ but it is indeed an abuse of notation.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for 
$$\lim\left\{\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k, \sum_{k=2}^\infty 1/k, \sum_{k=3}^\infty 1/k, \ldots\right\}$$

which would correspond to the meaningless:
$$\lim\left\{\infty, \infty, \infty, \ldots\right\}$$

So there is no real answer to the question. Although you could modify some standard definitions for limits and call this $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put it this way. Assume there is a natural number $n$ such that $\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{1}{k}$ is finite. Then there are a finite number of natural numbers less than $n$, and since adding on a finite number of terms to a convergent sequence will not affect convergence, we have that $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{1}{k}$ converges. But we see that this is a contradiction, as this is equal to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}$, which obviously diverges. Hence, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{1}{k}$ diverges. What does this tell you about the following set?
$$S=\left\{n\in\mathbb{N}:\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{1}{k}<\infty\right\}$$